# How to cancel GitHub Action job only for pull request, but not after merging?

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I have a GitHub Action which runs when create the pull request (`pull_request`), and also after merging to the main branch (`push`):

```
name: CodeQL
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
jobs:
  codeql:
    name: CodeQL
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Initialize CodeQL
        uses: github/codeql-action/init@v2
        with:
          languages: go
      - name: Autobuild
        uses: github/codeql-action/autobuild@v2
      - name: CodeQL
        uses: github/codeql-action/analyze@v2
```

Inside I am using [concurrency](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency):

```
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
```

### Case `pull_request`

When I update the pull request, it will cancel the previous job, which is great. In the GitHub Actions Summary -> Annotations, it shows

```
Canceling since a higher priority waiting request for 'CodeQL-refs/pull/6530/merge' exists
The operation was canceled.
```

### Case `push`

However, sometimes when two pull requests merge in very close time, the new merging to `main` branch's CodeQL will cancel the previous one too. It shows

```
Canceling since a higher priority waiting request for 'CodeQL-refs/heads/main' exists
The operation was canceled.
```

You can see now `${{ github.ref }}` will be always same `refs/heads/main`.

One workaround in my mind is duplicate this GitHub Action and have one for `pull_request` with `concurrency`, another one for `push` without `concurrency`.

Is there a way to only have one GitHub Action to avoid cancelling after merging to the `main` branch (only cancel for pull request)? Thanks!